# Can't add user to sudoers file

Tags: debian, sudo, linux-mint

I'm installing Globus Toolkit . When i try to setup Certificate , this error comes :

> ERROR:  could not run build command: /usr/local/globus-5.0.3/sbin/gpt-build -force /home/globus/.globus/simpleCA//globus_simple_ca_2e0087ee_setup-0.20.tar.gz

I think this may be due to denial of permission. I tried executing the file with 'sudo' . It says

> globus is not in sudoers file . This incident will be reported

I tried adding globus user to sudoers file .

For your reference ,
/etc/group file :

> sudo:x:27:globus,arul
>
> admin:x:1002:arul,globus

(I'm using Linux Mint debian . user arul has sudo privilege . But i've to install Globus in the globus user)

Comment: While phunehehe has answered your question, I doubt you really need to build Globus as root. If you describe *precisely* what you've been doing (what leads up to this error), people might be able to figure out what caused your build to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you add the user to sudoers, that user needs to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect. So, simply logging out and in should give your `globus` user sudo rights.

I'm assuming that you have the correct configuration in `/etc/sudoers`. To make `globus` a sudoer you need the line:

```
globus ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Or you need to add `globus` to the `wheel` group and then have the line:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Or some equivalent.

Comment: Im adding the sudoers file :

Comment: root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


%admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Comment: the user globus is in admin group - u can see that above . Have i done wrong in sudoers file ?

Comment: Yeah solved !!! . I added as your instr : globus ALL=(ALL) ALL . It worked . Thank you . thank u

Comment: @vettipayyan That's good :) Also see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4405/how-to-make-fedora-user-a-sudoer/4458#4458) on a related question.