# What is the command for listing all users who are members of the admin group?

Tags: fedora, users, group

I am looking for the name of the superusers list on Fedora. (On Ubuntu is seems to be "sudo".) I want to add one of the users to the superusers list.

The `groups` command only lists the groups of the current user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one superuser on Fedora and i.e. `root`. If you are looking for other user's who have the `sudo` privilege then you can look into /etc/sudoers file by executing command

> visudo

Here you can add any user to have the `sudo` privilege, by adding the following line at the end of the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
loginname ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out the format of the line that has to be added and edited your answer.

Comment: But unless you have a special use case, don't do that. Do [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4458/2511).

Comment: (Speaking as myself, not as a moderator.)

Comment: `visudo` *edits* the `sudoers` file; use it only if you want to modify it (yes, that's what the OP indirectly asked about). If you just want to view it, `cat /etc/sudoers` or `less /etc/sudoers` is sufficient. (You'll need root privileges for any of these, so `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`, for example.)

Answer (score 6):

To list all available groups with users in them you can use

```
getent group
```

or just look the content of `/etc/group` file.

By the way, on ubuntu there is only one superuser too. It is root. All others just are allowed to use it privilleges via sudo. You can modify rules in /etc/sudoers via `visudo` as mentioned above, if sudo is installed. This is true for any main stream GNU/Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

To add a user to a group, such as wheel your can use the `vigr` command.  You will also need to use `vigr -s` to update the shadow file.

Comment: I don't believe that is what the OP is asking. The question is how to find out what users have UID 0, or are in the group with sudo privileges.

Comment: At the end of the first paragraph he says "I want to add one of the users to the superusers list." If he adds the user to the groups a current super user is in using vigr and vigr -s he won't have to touch sudo as it will read the grorups file. This will handle other things the default superuser can do without resorting to sudo.

Answer (score 1):

“Superusers”, as in the users who can obtain administrative privileges, are the users who either know the `root` password or are authorized to execute commands as `root` with a mechanism such as `sudo`. These days, [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) is the most common and generally recommended mechanism.

There is no general rule to tell which users are allowed to gain privileges with `sudo`, it is a matter of convention. Look in the file `/etc/sudoers` for a line like

```
%sudo ALL = ALL
```

This means “Users in the group called `sudo` are allowed to run any command as any user”. Sometimes you'll see `(ALL)` after the equal sign: it's an optional way to restrict the line to work only on a particular machine (if you put a host name instead of `ALL`), which allows deploying the same configuration file to multiple machines with different intended privileges.

If there is such a line, you can add users to the `sudo` group:

```
adduser bob sudo
```

You can review who is a member of the `sudo` group by listing the group database:

```
getent group sudo
```

If there is no `%sudo` (or `%admin` or `%wheel`, as I said before the name is a matter of convention, and there can be more than one such entry), you can create one with `addgroup` and add the line to the `sudoers` file (use `visudo` to edit that file). Alternatively, instead of creating a group, you can add individual entries to the `sudoers` file (again, use `visudo` to edit this file):

```
bob ALL = ALL
```

Using a group makes management a little easier because you can see at a glance who is a member of this group.

Answer (score -1):

It is perfectly well possible to have more than one user with root privileges, it is uncommon to create them though. You can create a user and assign it UID 0, just make sure the first line in /etc/passwd is always for `root`. For most users it is bad practice to do this though.

To list all users with `root` privileges:

```
grep -E '^[^:]*:[^:]*:0:' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Technically, these aren't users with the same UID, but multiple entries for the same user in the group database. And this is pretty clearly not what the asker was asking about. Multiple entries for root do have their uses occasionally, but giving admin privileges to users is most emphatically not it.