# How to correctly enable sudo for user in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, sudo, users, root

I followed this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4405/how-to-make-fedora-user-a-sudoer) in order to enable `sudo` command for my created user. So I added it into the `wheels` group and edited the `/etc/sudoers` file accordingly.

But what I don't get about this is when I type for instance `sudo yum install`, it requires password of that user, not the password of `root`. This seems really insecure because if the account gets compromised, you can access `root`'s functions with that users password.

Shouldn't it work in the way that if you want `root` rights, than you need to know `root`'s password?

Comment: This is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how `sudo` works.  You trust the user and the user's actions are logged.

If you want to enter the root password, then you want to use the `su` command as follows:-

```
su -c yum install <package>
Password:
```

Once the command above finishes, you're returned to your normal user's prompt.

Comment: `su` is an older command that does what you want, but sudo was written so we don't need to pass root password to all the users. You should be able to configure PAM to let you login using a different system (ssh passphrase for example), then you would need 2 passwords to become root, but still your own passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Well it is how it's done. You will grant the permission to users of group `wheel` to perform administration duties. In short you grant them root access.

And this is not distro specific - in all Linux distributions and even BSDs you will do the same.

If you're worried about compromising security you could remove the user from sudoers table and go with `root`.

```
#> su root
Enter password
root #> yum install ...
```

This way you use root password and only root user has admin privileges.
Yes it is possible to do exotic setups with your sudoers table, but it's not really the routine way.

For all you could learn about `sudo` [visit here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo)

- `su` means *switch user*. So do `su root` to become root. `su <your_username>` will return your terminal prompt to `<your_usrname>`.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answerers said, this is the default behavior.

If you *really* want to enter the root password instead of the user's password, you can add the line

```
Defaults rootpw
```

to your `/etc/sudoers` file (use the `visudo` command, do **not** edit the `sudoers` file by any other means).

The usual disclaimer:

The defaults chosen for `sudo` are the way they are for a reason. Changing them may easily do you more harm than good. Read the man pages.

You could do worse than get a copy of Michael W. Lucas's [Sudo Mastery: User Access Control for Real People](https://www.tiltedwindmillpress.com/?product=sudo-mastery-user-access-control-for-everyone) if you really want to grok `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase security by restricting the commands that a "sudo user" can run.
This is highly recommended. This is the syntax on a Debian box I have, might be slightly different depending on the system.

```
Cmnd_Alias      USER_COMMAND = /bin/user_admin
someuser  ALL = PASSWD : USER_COMMAND
```

This way `someuser` can only run the command `/bin/user_admin` as root.
You can add multiple commands separated by a comma like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias      USER_COMMAND = /bin/user_admin,/sbin/fdisk,/some/other/cmd
```

For your specific system syntax you can check out `man sudoers`.

If you give away the root password, why would you need `sudo`?

The point of `sudo` is to give users super user privileges, without giving them full root access.